# My armature deformations inexplicably 'pop', without any shape keys or other modifiers. What's going on?

Tags: mesh, rigging

When I rotate my armature in certain positions, the mesh lurches outward into strange positions.  I've already checked out my weight painting, and there's no other modifiers causing any issues -- what's going on?

What could be?

Modifier actived: armature//corrective smooth

[image]

Here a picture from behind

[image]

Here the file:

[image]

Comment: There's some 5+ connected vertices, but they're well placed, shouldn't be an issue.  Your issue is that under 'Curved bones' in your 'petto' bone have 3 segments.  You shouldn't need more than 1 for the upper chest area, for most normal biped stuff anyways.  So, 1.  Select 'petto' in pose/edit mode 2.  Goto Properties >> Deform >> Curved bones. 3. Set segment number from 3 to 1.  This will solve the pop-issue your experiencing.

Comment: You are a genius . . . sorry i don't wanna to waste your time but can you exaplin why it works?

Comment: If you really want to have 3 segs, you can also select 'Multiply' in that same deformation tab.  I don't see too much of a difference in deformation granularity, but then again, maybe your doing some high-res stuff.  I don't know everything.

Comment: I'm no genius, I just had this problem before, and it took me forever to figure it out the first time it happened to me :P  In all honesty, I have no idea why the segments work, and other times don't work.  It probably has to do with the interpolation of certain rotations its getting from the original bone, but I'm not sure.  No clue about multiply either.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm going to edit your initial question.  This is actually a common problem that many riggers (especially coming from other software) have a hard time solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]When in doubt, check out the various settings in **Properties** >> **Bone Settings** >> **Deform** Tab.  If there's more than one segment under '**Curved Bones**', try dialing it down to 1.  While sub-dividing curved bones can lead to higher-resolution deformations, they are also problematic, and hard to trouble-shoot.  If you really want to have those high-resolution deformations, try selecting '**Multiply**' on the deformation settings for nearby, connected bones.  Also do lots of testing before animating.